# Streaming video over NRF24L01P

Tags: stm32, nrf24l01, cortex-m4, video-transmitter

Consider that we have compressed camera output video by `JPEG` using a Cortex-M4 MCU (Like STM32F407xxx that has a DCMI unit).
I want to know, Is it possible to stream a live video by `JPEG` and `NRF24L01P`?

I can show it theoretically by an example:

Expected resoulation is: 240x160 = 38400

Size of each RGB image (in bytes) = 38400 x 3 = 115200

Accoring to the JPEG wikipedia:

> JPEG typically achieves 10:1 compression with little perceptible loss
>   in image quality.

So, Comperssed size will be (in bytes) = 115200 / 10 = 11520

And, According to the nRF24L01+ product specification:

> It has user configurable parameters like frequency channel, output
>   power and air data rate. nRF24L01+ supports an air data rate of 250
>   kbps, 1 Mbps and 2Mbps.

Assume we working with 2Mbps. But due to packet headers and noises and... We consider that data rate value will be 1.5Mbps( = 196608 Bps).
So, FPS  of this video stream will be : 196608 / 11520 = 17 That can be acceptable.

Did I forget something? Is it possible in practice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: that wikipedia claim is **very** questionable. Also, when streaming video, use a video codec, not a still image encoder.

Comment: Thank you @MarcusMüller. I mean, we use a batch of jpeg images like `Motion JPEG` (M-JPEG or MJPEG) to streaming video.

Comment: that's not a video codec, that's just a still-image encoder encapsulated for video containers. I know you're computationally limited by your STM32, but if you can afford it at all, MPEG2 should be in the realm of the possible. People report they can do MPEG-4 HEVC using x264 on a processor like yours in ~18 million clock cycles per frame – that might or might not be enough for you.

Comment: Theoretically, of course, video streaming is possible (as well as by any other digital link). The main question is frame rate (baudrate of nRF24), or if you get the slideshow. I have read the article in Russian (unfortunately, I can't find it now) about testing of nRF24L01+ for maximal real life baudtrate. Continuous streaming on 2Mbps with no handshake, CRC, validation etc. The maximum achieved real speed was about 300-500 kbps because of nRF work logic. 2Mbps baudrate includes every bit in packet (e.g. headers, addresses etc), not just useful data, and you also have pauses between packets.

Comment: @cyclone125 I think you could make that an answer